# Is it now safe to get shot by a Dalek?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

In episode 9.2,

> Clara and Missy escape the Daleks by using the energy from the rays they shot at them to power their teleporters. Missy explained how the Doctor had done something similar in the past, but the difference is that in Clara and Missy's case the rays did not strike the device directly, which implies it's enough to have a device that can use the energy anywhere on yourself.
>
> In theory it may even be possible to use a device that does something other than teleport you, or maybe nothing at all.

Using the knowledge above, what stops anyone who has access to such technology to use it as a shield, allowing them to get shot by Daleks with no ill effects?

Comment: Even if you have a shield, you have to be able to anticipate the sword strike and counter it at just the right time. Time Lords in particular are known to have much faster reflexes than your average human, for instance.

Comment: @Geobits: I don't think that works in this case. Missy might have anticipated the strike, but Clara didn't even know there was a way to counter it. It worked anyway.

Comment: Maybe I missed something when watching, but I was under the impression that *Missy* saved them both, with Clara doing nothing. Teleporters can take more than one person along IIRC.

Comment: @Geobits: Clara was shot many seconds, perhaps a full minute after Missy. Missy would have to have expected exactly when Clara would be shot, if she triggered the teleportation, without being able to see there.

Comment: The devices where destroyed in the process, making it a one time only defence, unless you happen to have lots of time vortex manipulators on hand

Comment: @CarlSixsmith: Is that so? I hadn't noticed. It would still be good to have it as a one-time defence, though.

Comment: @GeorgeT yes Missy states that the blast destroyed them

Answer (score 7):

There existing a possible defence against a certain type of energy weapon does not magically mean the energy weapon is inherently "safe".

So, no, it's not suddenly "safe" to get shot by a Dalek.